# Explanation of fold method of spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am running Spark-1.4.0 pre-built for Hadoop-2.4 (in local mode) to calculate the sum of squares of a DoubleRDD. My Scala code looks like

```
sc.parallelize(Array(2., 3.)).fold(0.0)((p, v) => p+v*v)
```

And it gave a surprising result `97.0`.

This is quite counter-intuitive compared to the Scala version of `fold`

```
Array(2., 3.).fold(0.0)((p, v) => p+v*v)
```

which gives the expected answer `13.0`.

It seems quite likely that I have made some tricky mistakes in the code due to a lack of understanding. I have read about how the function used in `RDD.fold()` should be communicative otherwise the result may depend on partitions and etc. So example, if I change the number of partitions to 1,

```
sc.parallelize(Array(2., 3.), 1).fold(0.0)((p, v) => p+v*v)
```

the code will give me `169.0` on my machine!

Can someone explain what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it is actually pretty well explained by the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

> Aggregate the elements of each partition, and then the results for all the partitions, using a given associative and commutative function and a neutral "zero value". The function op(t1, t2) is allowed to modify t1 and return it as its result value to avoid object allocation; however, it should not modify t2.
>
> This behaves somewhat differently from fold operations implemented for non-distributed collections in functional languages like Scala. This fold operation may be applied to partitions individually, and then fold those results into the final result, rather than apply the fold to each element sequentially in some defined ordering. For functions that are not commutative, the result may differ from that of a fold applied to a non-distributed collection.

To illustrate what is going on lets try to simulate what is going on step by step:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(2., 3.))

val byPartition = rdd.mapPartitions(
    iter => Array(iter.fold(0.0)((p, v) => (p +  v * v))).toIterator).collect()
```

It gives us something similar to this `Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0)` and

```
byPartition.reduce((p, v) => (p + v * v))
```

returns 97

Important thing to note is that results can differ from run to run depending on an order in which partitions are combined.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation confirmed my suspect - `(2*2) * (2*2) + (3*3) * (3*3) = 97`. And in the second case, it is like `(2*2 + 3*3) * (2*2 + 3*3) = 169`. I guess that is the reason why `foldLeft` and `foldRight` have no correspondence in spark - order simply doesn't make sense in "distributed" fold.

Comment: Actually in a following case `Array(2., 3.)` you can even get  25 or 85, hence my last comment. Generally speaking if function is not commutative and associative weird things can happen. Correct way of handling things here would be to map and then fold: `rdd.map(x => x * x).fold(0.0)(_ + _)`.

Comment: What is interesting PySpark seems to handle things differently and returns 13 for (2., 3.) input O_o, with the same number of partitions.

Comment: I think pyspark has the same restriction too, see the following results

`sc.parallelize([2., 3.]).fold(0.0, lambda p,v : p+v*v)` generates `49`

`sc.parallelize([2., 3.], 100).fold(0.0, lambda p,v : p+v*v)` generates `13`

Comment: Yes it has. It just applies the function in `op(obj, acc)` instead of `op(acc, obj)` so if there is only one element in partition it is not squared in the `mapPartitions` phase :)